# When running npm install in an angular project is the angular cli installed

Tags: angular-cli, npm-install

Downloaded an application built on Angular 7 from a Git repo. Then ran `npm install`. Is the `angular cli` automatically installed when doing this? Do I need to install it manually? If not will the latest angular cli work with an older version of angular? In my case v7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you running `npm install` the `Angular CLI` gets installed locally for your project. Then, when you run `npm start` or `npm run ng <your command>` it will kick off.

If you want to install the latest Angular CLI globally, you can do so by running `npm install @angular/cli -g`

Then when you run `ng <command>` in your project directory, for commands like scaffolding - `ng g <params>` or `ng update` the global CLI will be in use.

However you do not have to install CLI globally, as I mentioned above, you will be fine with the local one, only the downside of that you have to prefix all your CLI commands with `npm run` e.g `npm run ng g c my-component` which is a bit of inconvenient.

But if you want to play around with the latest CLI and to scaffold new projects, then you have to install it globally.

Answer (score 0):

Good evening. I assume you have to install the Angular CLI. Please visit https://angular.io/guide/setup-local for detailed instructions.